# Is there a better way to change css attributes dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

I'm trying to change CSS attributes dynamically for given elements in the document, my current solution is something like this :

```
function changeEffect(element,choice){

  var effects = {};

  effects.name1  = {"-webkit-box-shadow" : "7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                      "-moz-box-shadow"     : "7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                      "box-shadow"          : "7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                     },
  effects.name2  = {"-webkit-filter"    : "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)",
                        "filter"            : "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)"                       
                       };


  for(i in effects[choice]){
    if(effects[choice].hasOwnProperty(i)){
       // using jquery to easily apply changes
       $(element).css(i,effects[choice][i]);
    }

  }                       
}
```

for example if i want to apply  the effect **name1** to all elements with the class *img*, then the code is :

```
changeEffect('.img','name1');
```

my question is

> Is there any better solution for similar task ?

Comment: Voted for closing for this is primarily opinion based. I think your solution is pretty good. The code speaks for itself. So do not change. Others will have other solutions that also work, maybe more or less efficient..

Comment: usually what you're defining as object.properties would be defined in the CSS stylesheet, should make a test to see which one is more efficient ..

Comment: yes @maioman you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You now define name1 and name2 each time when all you have to do is use something like [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) with appropriate CSS

```
$(".img").toggleClass("name1 name2");
```

Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#click").on("click",function() {
    $(".img").toggleClass("name1 name2");
  });
});
```

```css
.name1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.name2 {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="click">Click</span>
<div class="img name1">Hello</div>
```

Comment: I do like this as well

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `css()` function can handle object of key/value pairs in a single call: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

```
function changeEffect(element,choice){

  var effects = {};

  effects.name1  = {"-webkit-box-shadow" : "7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                      "-moz-box-shadow"     : "7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                      "box-shadow"          : "7px 13px 21px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                     },
  effects.name2  = {"-webkit-filter"    : "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)",
                        "filter"            : "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)"};

  $(element).css(effects[choice]);

}
```